# Website is very slow after loading 20k products to Opencart Journal Theme (version 3.x)

Tags: performance, opencart, pagespeed, opencart-3, opencart-module

Website was very slow compared to previous , what we done is uploaded 20k products to opencart admin panel . After that we found that its takes 2mins to load the home page at the same time category filters didnt worked (due to server timeout more than 3mins) . Installed Nitro and they helped us to load in 1.5 mins , then we had done image optimization/query optimization/ Journal theme customization/ Index Creation/etc but still it takes 30 to 40 sec to load home page and also category filters (JOURNAL THEME INBUILT FEATURE) still taking lot more time to load. Can anyone help us to proceed

Comment: This issue can stem from a number of things, and it may have nothing to do with opencart itself. For example, what type of web hosting service are you using? Is it shared, VPS, or dedicated? Are you using any other customizations/mods besides the open journal theme? Besides having a large number of products, do you also have a large number of categories as well? Things like disabling the category count can also help.

Comment: If you are using **Journal v.3.0.20** (the latest so far), then you must be using at least **Opencart v.2.3.x** and above. Edit your question and add the results of https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ so we can help you.